# Access violation on std::function assigned to a lambda

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

I was trying to play around with std::function and std::bind and I stepped in a problem. I would like to build a general structure that allows me to bind a std::function to a member function without knowing a priori the arguments of the member function. I wrote this thing

```
template<typename Class, typename Return, typename ...Args>
struct Caller
{
private:
    std::function<Return(Args ...)> callerFunction;

    Caller(const Caller&) = delete;
    Caller(Caller&&) = delete;
    Caller& operator=(const Caller&) = delete;

public:
    ~Caller() = default;
    Caller() = default;

    Caller(Class& instance, Return(Class::*function)(Args...))
    {
        callerFunction = [&](Args... args) { return (instance.*function)(args...); };
    }

    Return operator() (Args ... args)
    {
        return callerFunction(args...);
    }
};
```

FYI I know that the arguments to the function are passed by value (I encountered some problem using universal references with variadic template, I will work on that later).

The problem here is that when I fire the function with operator() I get an Access Violation Error. I tried to narrow down the problem and created a structure without the variadic arguments (allowing the member function to have just an int as argument) and I saw that assigning the lambda to the std::function was given me the same error, but if I used std::bind with a placeholder everything was just fine.

The test ground is this

```
class A
{
public:
    bool foo(int a)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo(9);

    Caller<A, bool, int> caller(a, &A::foo);
    caller(10);

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Using the lambda, do I need to save the instance of the class in order to call properly the member function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have UB.  In the constructor for `Caller`, you pass the member function pointer by value, (so a copy of the pointer would be created that only exists inside of the constructor,) but then capture that in the lambda by reference.  So by the time you call `caller(10)` the pointer is out of scope.  `instance` is fine in this example since you pass that to the constructor by reference, and `a` is still in scope when you call `caller(10)`.  (Although you should assume that will change in the future and design around that.)

Comment: It's also worth noting that there already exists a `std::mem_fn` that should work fine with lambdas or `std::bind`.

Comment: Ok understood. What I don't understand is how I can fix this issue.
About instance: at startup of the program I will have some classes instantiated and those variables will be available until the end of the program.

Comment: @0x5453 The UB you refer to is when I use the bind instead of the lambda?

Comment: The UB is reading a variable (the member function pointer) that has gone out of scope.  To fix you can capture the pointer by value, so that the lambda will have it's own copy of the pointer that won't go out of scope.  For `instance`, that's fine as long as you keep that invariant true everywhere.  Probably leave some comments too so your future self doesn't forget.  (If you ever *do* want the lambda to outlive the object, I would probably pass and capture a `std::shared_ptr<Class>` by value so that it will keep living without creating a copy, since `Class` could potentially be very large.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As state in comment, you have dangling pointer of `function`, you could use instead:

```
Caller(Class& instance, Return(Class::*function)(Args...))
{
    callerFunction = [&instance, function](Args... args) {
        return (instance.*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Note: `instance` should also outlives `Caller`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `[&]` when the object or copies of it outlives the current scope.

You are capturing references to local variables and storing them beyond the current scope.